# A translation for 'stirrup'

Tags: vocabulary, etymology

I have to translate the word 'stirrup' into Latin. Since the Romans (famously) rode without stirrups  I can find no useful classical reference and have decided to use *stapes*, which is used by physicians to describe the smallest bone in the human body (in the ear).

The bone is exactly of the right shape. Does anyone know the origin of this word? Or has any opinion or advice on its declension? My instinct is for 3rd Decl., gen. *stapitis*, rather than 5th, gen *stapei*.

Comment: *Ainsworth* marks *stapes* *-edis* with an asterisk (borrowed/ late /dictionaries) and attributes it to *Jun.*  Alternative, from an inscription, *stapia.*

Comment: @Hugh Can you add that information to your answer? It's part of the answer, not a comment, the way it looks to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I've been able to determine, it might come from a Germanic word cognate with English "step" (from PGmc **stap-iz* "step, stirrup"), or it might be a Late Latin combination of *sta-* "stand" and *ped-* "foot". Or both!

Either way, the declension was *stapēs, stapedis*, and it's [well-attested in post-classical sources](http://www.neulatein.de/words/start2.htm?../words/1/015565.htm). I'd say you've definitely made the right choice.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed, and especially thanks for pointing me to gen. _stapedis_, which feels much more comfortable than _stapitis_ (which I formed on the pattern of _stipes_.

Answer (score 1):

In *Ainsworth* English-Latin there are three words for **Stirrup.**

> *A stirop,* or *stirrup,* Scabelum, *vel* scamillum, equestre pendulum ; subex pedaneus, //* stapes.

*Stapes is not included in the main Latin-English section, but in a later section. *"obsoletae, dubiae, corruptae Latinitatis."*

> Stapes, edis, m *A stirrup,* Jun. Stapia, f. *Vet. Inscript.*

*Scamillum, i n.* (also *scamillus -i* m.) a footstool, a little bench. [so... a hanging equstrian foot-support]
*Subex, -icis* f  (1) anything put under,*(Ennius)* (2) a stirrup (Bud.)

*Voss.* a dictionary writer quoted by Ainsworth gives alternative spellings.

> Strepa, *al.* Strapa, Stapes *Voss.* Strepus *pro* Strepus *vel* Stropus *vel* Stroppus *Id.*

and from Isidore, Spanish Bishop of Seville, encyclopaedist 'Etymologies':

> Strupes, *id. quod* Scalmus *Isid.*

*Scalmus* is a primitive rowlock, a round piece of wood to which the oar is attached with a leather **strap** (and by synecdoche a boat) both uses Cicero

Comment: Thank you, although I think that you've missed the point of the question. I have already chosen _stapes_ as the word to use, and wish to know its origin, if possible, and (also if possible) to be directed to its proper declension.

Comment: Clearly I didn't signpost **Stapes, edis, m A stirrup,** clearly enough. But I'm still not convinced that **step** is the etymology, compared with **στροφ-** and **strop** (naval) *a loop,* and **strep, strap, stroppus** a tie, a binding.  And now I've run into too many *culs de sac* to take it further.

Comment: And the answer to your third question, is that ***stapia*** (ancient inscriptions may be the earliest usage. The earliest **dateable** form is ***stapeda, -ae, f.*** in Folieto author of *'de avibus'* etc. fl.1130.